# RAID 10 SSD Benchmarks

Tags: ssd, raid10

I haven't been able to find any benchmarks for the following setup:
Intel Cherry 520 SSD x 4 RAID10 with LSI 9260 writeback-cache enabled.

I'm looking to get 1.5gbps sequential

Comment: Is that 1.5 Gigabytes/second or 1.5 Gigabits/second? ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is either a request for product recommendation, or an extremely specialised question which is likely to be of interest to very few others.

Answer (score 2):

You won't get 1.5 Gigabytes/second sequential or otherwise on this setup.

The RAID controller and drives you're considering each have a theoretical maximum throughput of 6 Gigabits/second (Gbps), or 600 Megabytes/second. The [drive specifications](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/ssd-520-specification.html) suggest sustained reads of 550 Megabytes/second and writes of 520 Megabytes/second. In a RAID 10 configuration, writes will fall below your expected goal.

You would need more disks to accomplish this.